# Handle starvation in apache commons-pool

Tags: java, apache-commons-pool

I am using 1.6 version of apache commons-pool library. As per the javadoc,

whenExhaustedAction specifies the behavior of the borrowObject() method when the pool is exhausted:
It can be either  WHEN_EXHAUSTED_FAIL,  WHEN_EXHAUSTED_GROW, or  WHEN_EXHAUSTED_BLOCK.

I want to use the borrowObject and if don't get the object within a specified timeframe, I need some sort of handle to handle the scenario(like i will be rescheduling the tasks, if i don't get the target object)

But the only option, I get here is NoSuchElementException which is a RuntimeException, which I need to catch and handle the error scenario. I am quite sceptical about catching the RuntimeException

Is this the intended way of handling object starvation with GenericObjectPool or do I have any other options ?

Answer (score 2):

I've looked at the `borrowObject` [documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/api-1.6/org/apache/commons/pool/ObjectPool.html#borrowObject%28%29) and it states that it throws these exceptions

> ```
> IllegalStateException - after close has been called on this pool.
> Exception - when makeObject throws an exception.
> NoSuchElementException - when the pool is exhausted and cannot or will not return another instance.
> ```

Because `NoSuchElementException` is a documented behavior of this method, there is nothing wrong with catching it around `borrowObject` and handling to your liking.

I suggest you catch it right around the call and wrap with one of your own, so if other method in your function throws `NoSuchElementException` the high level handler is not confused with pool exhaustion.  Wrapper exception can be either checked or runtime, depending on your preference and project requirements.

e.g

```
final T obj;

try
{
  obj = pool.borrowObject( );
}
catch ( NoSuchElementException ex )
{
  throw new MyPoolExhausetdException( ex );
}

// Do something with obj
```